# When printing with canvg the cart labels are behind the chart

Tags: javascript, canvg

http://jsfiddle.net/jjhii/46bv10db/1/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px">data</canvas>
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), svg);
```

Another view, easier to see the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/46bv10db/5/

In the above example you can see where the labels on the right are behind the chart in the PNG file.  The original chart has these labels on the right.  Basically there is two problems in concept.  The first is the cart is too wide in the print out (PNG file).  The second is the labels are behind.  I would prefer to fix the chart sixe but I can live with at least putting the labels in front.

Any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The output was from a D3 chart.  I changed the attr function when creating the labels from x,y,width,height to matrix.  The PNG file is now correct.  Note the commented out line are what I removed.

```
    var x = (width + 5).toString();
    var y1 = ((height / 4) + (30 * i) + 5).toString();
    var y2 = ((height / 4) + (30 * i)).toString();

    focus.append("svg:text")
        //.attr("dx", x)
        //.attr("dy", y2)
        //.attr("width", "100")
        //.attr("height", "10")
        //.attr("class", "rightLabel")
        //.attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .attr("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, " + x + ", " + y2 + ")")
        .attr("font-family", "ArialMT")
        .attr("font-size", "12")
        .text(rightText[i]);
```